# AngularJS Calling the controller method from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Prompt as from a directive to cause a method of the controller.
Directive

```
app.directive('scroll', function($location){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('scroll', function(){
                let fh = $('#ngview').height();
                let nh = Math.round($(element).height()  + $(element).scrollTop());
                if(fh == nh){
                    //Here we do what we need 
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

HTML markup

```
<div class="col-md-12 middle-body" scroll>
    <div ng-show="showUserModal" ng-include="'partial/loginModal.html'"></div>
    <div class="user-loader" ng-show="loading">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view id="ngview">
    </div>
</div>
```

`app` is the main application module

```
var app = angular.module('app', 
[
    'ngRoute',
    'lastUpdateModule',
    'selectedByGenreModule',
    'currentFilmModule',
    'httpFactory',
    'userModule',
    'accountModule'
]);
```

The controller from which you want to call the method is described in a separate file
and connects via require

```
const SelectedByGenreModule = require('../controllers/selectedByGenre.controller.js')
```

and passed as a dependency to the main module

So it is from this controller that I need to call the method in the directive.
Tell me how to do it correctly. I left through $rootScope but it did not work out
As far as I know, the directive has the same scope as the controller in which it is located. That is, the directive is in the controller which is the parent for the controller from which you need to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your directive to trigger an action defined by your controller. I'd recommend passing the function to the directive via the `scope` property. See the example below.

```js
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', []);

app.directive('scroll', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      scroll: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('scroll', function() {
        let fh = $('#ngview').height();
        let nh = Math.round($(element).height() + $(element).scrollTop());
        if (fh == nh) {
          scope.scroll();
        }
      })
    }
  }
});

app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.onScroll = function() {
    console.log('Scrolled!')
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12 middle-body" scroll="onScroll">
    <div ng-show="showUserModal" ng-include="'partial/loginModal.html'"></div>
    <div class="user-loader" ng-show="loading">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view id="ngview">
  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At me visibility of the controller in which there is a necessary method is limited ng-view in parameter it is necessary to transfer above in a partitioning. Will this work?

Comment: If the directive uses isolate scope, it should use expression `'&'` binding to call methods in a parent scope. That will make migration to Angular 2+ easier. For more informatiion, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Answer (score 0):

You can require parent controllers using the `require` property when defining the directive, the `^^` tells angular to look up the DOM for a parent, otherwise it will only look on the local element.

```
app.directive('scroll', function($location){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^^selectedByGenreCtrl', // Use the correct controller name here
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, selectedByGenreCtrl){
            element.on('scroll', function(){
                let fh = $('#ngview').height();
                let nh = Math.round($(element).height()  + $(element).scrollTop());
                if(fh == nh){
                    //Here we do what we need 
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```